# Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?

Tags: math-mode, equations, syntax

I've heard that you should use `\[ ... \]` for displayed equations instead of  `$$ ... $$`, but why is that?

I'd assumed that it's so that you can more easily tell which are starting and which are ending delimiters, but if I always use a syntax-highlighting text editor, I can see that easily based on the color of the symbols.

Is there any reason for this suggestion?

Comment: I tend to prefer amsmath `\begin{equation*}` over `\[`, because it feels more semantic and makes the source more human-readable. But I really don't know, is there any difference between these two?

Comment: @Juan: If you use amsmath, there is no difference. See the end of amsmath.sty.

Comment: @Harald At least when using `lineno`, there is a difference... [why doesnt lineno number a paragraph when it is followed by an indented equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25784/why-doesnt-lineno-number-a-paragraph-when-it-is-followed-by-an-indented-equation)

Comment: @David: I see – so the `lineno` package redefines `\[…\]`? Well, seeing as this is peculiar to that package, if you really want an answer you should probably post a separate question. (I can't help you with it, sorry.)

Comment: @Harald ... actually, the incompatibility is between `lineno` and `$$..$$`

Comment: Is /begin{displaymath} wrong as well, or can I use that?

Comment: Here's a concrete example where $$ fails and \[ succeeds: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25784/why-doesnt-lineno-number-a-paragraph-when-it-is-followed-by-an-indented-equatio

Comment: What is the LaTeX equivalent of $...$ then ie inline math?

Comment: @user71207 --- It's \\( ... \\).

Comment: Side note, in LaTeX both `$` and `\(` are accepted, see [best practices - Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode) ■ Another concrete example where `$$` causes "mysterious bugs": [math mode - Weird small indentation after formula - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649690/weird-small-indentation-after-formula?noredirect=1#649694)

Comment: `\qedhere` works with `\[ ... \]` but not with `$$ ... $$`. Edit: Ah, this is actually cited below!

Comment: Leaving this here for any UNIX+git users who want to replace `$$ ... $$` by `\[ ... \]` in their entire project: `git ls-files '*.tex' | xargs perl -i -p0e 's/\$\$([^\$]*)\$\$/\\[$1\\]/gs'` (Sorry for deleting and reposting this a few times. Should be correct now.)

Answer (score 469, accepted):

`$$` is TeX primitive syntax, which, as others have commented is hard to redefine (in classic TeX there is no command name which triggers entering or leaving display math).

LaTeX doesn't officially support `$$`. The most noticeable failure if you use the syntax is that the `fleqn` option will no longer affect the display of the mathematics, it will remain centered rather than being set flush left.

However if you are using `\[` it is best to use the `amsmath` package (it is best to load this package if doing any serious mathematical layout with LaTeX).

`\[` is a short form of `\begin{displaymath}` which one might expect to act like an un-numbered form of `\begin{equation}`. The `amsmath` package redefines `\[` to be `\begin{equation*}` which is exactly an un-numbered form of the `equation` environment as defined by that package. In the core LaTeX definition `\[` has the definition

```
  \ifvmode
     \nointerlineskip
     \makebox[.6\linewidth]{}%
  \fi
  $$
```

which means that the spacing if used between paragraphs is better that a primitive `$$` (which causes a blank paragraph just consisting of the indentation and parfillskip glue to be inserted before the display) but it is inconsistent with `equation` and always uses `\abovedisplayskip` rather than `\abovedisplayshortskip`. In the AMS versions the spacing is more consistent,

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the effect of the `\makebox`?

Comment: well as indicated it's an attempt to improve the behaviour if the equation starts a paragraph, `$$` would force a blank line aligned on baselineskip but with just with just an indentation box and parfillskip glue then have the display skip, that forces the paragraph tp start with a zero height line which reduces the vertical space.

Comment: Hello @DavidCarlisle, is it correct to say that `\[` `\]` is equivalent to `$$` `$$` like `\(` `\)` is equivalent to `$` `$`?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi no they are not equivalent and unlike single `$` , the syntax `$$`  is not supported in latex at all.

Comment: is there a way to summarize your answer into a concise clear reason? Is it just "$ $ is not latex"? If it's not then why have I been able to compile latex just fine for 10 years on any editor on my computer to overleaf etc.? I can't extract the main point from your answer, can you help me? thanks for your time!

Comment: @CharlieParker tex is a macro expansion language so there is no compilation or code hiding, all lower level constructs are necessarily available and so can be used. But the fact that they do not give errors does not mean that they should be used. If you use documented latex math constructs they will be centred or flush left depending on whether you use the `fleqn` option. `$$` is always centred: the official latex documentation does not need to mention that `fleqn` does not work with `$$` because `$$` is not mentioned at all.

Comment: `$$` is hard to redefine? It doesn't look very hard to me. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60395/250119 What's the issue with that answer?

Comment: @user202729 you did read the first line of that answer? also that doesn't really redefine the $$ display math function, it just prevents it being called.

Answer (score 199):

Spacing is wrong.

It is a "deadly sin" according to l2tabu, section 1.6 on page 6:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/

Comment: Ooh... that's a nice link.

Comment: should be "required reading"

Comment: Maybe worth noting that the difference between \[ .. \] and $$ .. $$ is larger than that between \( .. \) and $ .. $.  _If_ your document is completely correct, you will not (I think) notice the difference between the latter in the final document but you will with the former.

Comment: Although the link is good, I find the answer a bit disappointing: _What_ is wrong with the spacing? This explanation is also missing in l2tabu.

Comment: @Andrew: The reason you can't see any difference between `\(…\)` and `$…$` is that they former expands into the latter (plus some error checking).

Comment: @Jasper: Well, you quoted _everything_ l2tabu has to offer on the subject. And yes, it does say that _something_ is wrong with the spacing of `$$`, but it doesn't say _what_ is wrong. That's what I actually meant in my comment above. Anyway, thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: @Jasper: My question above was not a rethorical one; I honestly don't know and really would like to know the answer, too.

Comment: Amusingly, `l2tabuen.pdf` suggests to use `$\uppi$` rather than `\(\uppi\)` on page 14. So `$$...$$` is “please don't do this” and a “deadly sin”, because of spacing in _some_ cases (I have not seen a single one to date) and its `TeX` nature, while `$...$` is perfectly correct? Oh, please. Yes, the use of `fleqn` and some other arguments are understandable and I do use LaTeX commands, but the issue has gone too far without a good argumentation which the one in `l2tabuen.pdf` is certainly not.

Comment: One interesting effect of reading this document is that I now have far more obsolete commands in my head because there are some I was just never aware of, even though I use the endorsed versions. I'm not really sure what is so bad about setting \parskip and \parindent, either. I get that it changes it for environments as well but isn't that sometimes an advantage?

Comment: This answer is mysterious and should be edited to provide additional context.

Comment: is there a way to summarize your answer into a concise clear reason? Is it just "$ $ is not latex"?

Comment: Well, there's an elaboration in [Display math deadly sin in l2tabu - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21173/display-math-deadly-sin-in-l2tabu?noredirect=1&lq=1) .

Answer (score 174):

Here is one more reason (this is what converted me). If you use the `\begin{proof}...\end{proof}` environment, you occasionally end a proof with an equation. The automatic QED box then ends up on a line by itself, which is ugly. You can fix this by writing `\qedhere` at the end of the equation, but this doesn't work properly with `$$...$$` – you have to use `\[...\]` (or an environment, like `equation`/`gather`/`align`). To exemplify:

*Don't*:

```
\begin{proof}
  This follows from
  $$e^{x+y}=e^xe^y. \qedhere$$
\end{proof}
```

*Do*:

```
\begin{proof}
  This follows from
  \[e^{x+y}=e^xe^y. \qedhere\]
\end{proof}
```

Comment: But when you use `\begin{proof}`, you dont need to put `\quedhere`, it is automatic and is displayed at the end of the line like your second example. Anyway, i'm going to start using `\[ \]`

Comment: @LuisFelipe Have you tried it?  Without `\qedhere`, the box ends up on the line after the equation.  It's more noticeable with a longer equation, but it happens in this case as well.

Comment: The ''problem'' with $$ can be easily solved adding `\hspace{}` to both sides of the equation. I am still not converted.

Comment: @luchonacho --- But why go to the trouble? Why not just use the supported syntax?

Answer (score 50):

`$$` is plain TeX and could have some side effects, also `fleqn` will  not work anymore. Please have a look at [l2tabu](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf). In my opinion the best environment for equations is `gather` or `align`. If you use `equation` you sometimes get some strange spacings.

Comment: `eqnarray` gives strange spacing and is deprecated in favour of `align` – `equation`, on the other hand, should be fine …

Comment: The reason fleqn doesn't work with $$...$$ is because it redefines \\] to run some code at the end.

Answer (score 40):

It is **not** always preferable to use `\[..\]`!

The `source2e.pdf` file contains the documented source of `LaTeX2e`. Therein, one sees that `\[..\]` is essentially a wrapper for `$$ .. $$` checking if the construct is used  when already in math mode (which is then an error).

> Produces $$...$$ with checks that `\[` isn’t used in math mode, and that
>   `\]` is only used in math mode begun with `\]`.

There seems to be a typo there `\[` was meant. Besides, the sentence should not be taken to mean that

```
\[ a^n + b^n= c^n $$
$$ a^n + b^n= c^n \]
```

create errors, they don't, only things like `\( a^n + b^n= c^n \]` or `$a^n + b^n= c^n \]` do.

However the detailed source code shows that it contains something which will interfere in some cases with correct vertical spacing:

```
170 \def\[{%
171 \relax\ifmmode
172 \@badmath
173 \else
174 \ifvmode
175 \nointerlineskip
176 \makebox[.6\linewidth]{}%
177 \fi
178 $$%%$$ BRACE MATCH HACK
179 \fi
180 }
181 \def\]{%
182 \relax\ifmmode
183 \ifinner
184 \@badmath
185 \else
186 $$%%$$ BRACE MATCH HACK
187 \fi
188 \else
189 \@badmath
190 \fi
191 \ignorespaces
192 }
```

The `\makebox[.6\linewidth]{}` which is executed when the display is opened in vertical mode has  the effect of disabling the `TeX` use of `\abovedisplayshortskip` (hence of `\belowdisplayshortskip`). The problem is that immediately after `\[..\]` `TeX` is in `horizontal` mode (not `vertical`) hence if two or more equations are typeset using `\[..\]` without anything in-between, the second and next ones will use the *short* skips. This leads to incoherent vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

The rules are smashed so take no vertical space, and are only there to
illustrate the issue (extra vertical space only between the first and the second
equation and not between the next ones).

Using \verb|\[..\]|: 

\[
\vartheta=2\pi\smash{\rule{.4pt}{4ex}}  
\]
\[
\vartheta=2\pi\smash{\rule{.4pt}{4ex}}  
\]
\[
\vartheta=2\pi\smash{\rule{.4pt}{4ex}}  
\]

Using \verb|$$..$$|:

$$
  \vartheta=2\pi\smash{\rule{.4pt}{4ex}}
$$
$$
  \vartheta=2\pi\smash{\rule{.4pt}{4ex}}  
$$
$$
  \vartheta=2\pi\smash{\rule{.4pt}{4ex}}  
$$

There is no issue if we use \verb|\[..\]| but start within a paragraph:\newline
\[
\vartheta=2\pi\smash{\rule{.4pt}{4ex}}  
\]
\[
\vartheta=2\pi\smash{\rule{.4pt}{4ex}}  
\]
\[
\vartheta=2\pi\smash{\rule{.4pt}{4ex}}  
\]
The issue arises only if the chain of \verb|\[..\]| is initiated in vertical
mode. The issue never arises when using the original \verb|$$..$$| input syntax.

\end{document}
```

[image: bad vertical spacing with displaymath]

Comment: amsmath `\[` doesn't suffer from this bug.

Comment: It's wrong using two `\[...\]` constructions in a row to begin with. So this answer doesn't add anything, I'm afraid.

Comment: @egreg you mean that being better informed adds nothing? your comment is opinionated, so let me explicitely write for the record that I definitely do not share this opinion of yours.

Comment: @giordano indeed, that's true and is good to know, I had not checked that. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @jfbu Sorry to hear that. My opinion stems from 20+ years of experience with LaTeX and I have no problem in stating it again and again. Fixing a bug introducing worse bugs is surely not a recommendable remedy.

Comment: @egreg to clear up potential misunderstanding I meant to say I was in disagreement with your opinion about my answer not adding anything, not with your strong recommendation not to use multiple `\[..\]` in a row. Most of the time I am with `align` of `amsmath`. But this has its own problems too.

Answer (score 29):

[Edit: I should add the disclaimer that the following is based on just "I read it somewhere sometime ago", so I have no references to backup my claims.]

As far as I know `$$ ... $$` is a TeX, amsTeX thing. LaTeX still supports it for one reason or another, but the "proper" one to use, as defined in the specifications, is `\[ ... \]`. All this just means that they are not promising that `$$` will always work. So it is technically possible (though unlikely in the near future), that compatibility with `$$` is removed from LaTeX and lots of your documents break.

As to why one is in the specifications and not the other? I have no idea.

Comment: Given that TeX goes into display math mode by the occurrence of two identical characters with catcode 3, LaTeX would have to go through some contortions to prevent `$$ ... $$` from working, especially if `$ ... $` was still to work. I guess you could give some other character catcode 3, make `$` active, define it using `\@ifnextchar` to look for another `$` and give an error message, otherwise use the new math shift character to go into or out of math mode and of course after the definition of `$`, make the other character have its original catcode...but that doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: LuaTeX have primitives for entering/exiting inline and display math modes (as well as sub/superscript), so making it possible to assign $ a normal catcode.

Comment: @TH: So *that's* why `$$` still sorta works in LaTeX. I've been wondering why they couldn't disable it, and I seem to have misplaced my TeXbook.

Comment: A workaround could be setting the default math typeface (appearing with `$$`) to a big red blinking all-caps font saying "you shouldn't use this", and then setting `\[...\]` to change this mess back to something normal. Would this work? I am no TeX guru, so I do not know for sure.

Answer (score 24):

1. While my memory prevents me from naming the guilty software, I have seen LaTeX syntax highlighting become confused by the `$$ ... $$` construct when it parsed the `\[ ... \]` construct correctly.
2. Agreed, worry about some partially broken editor isn't a high priority. But, I have found that I am more than partially broken. If I've made a mess of a file, the left-hand and right-hand information in the `\[` way has, on occasion, helped me figure out just what I was on about more easily than the symmetric `$$` would have.

Comment: While this is certainly true enough, it's not the real reason. The real reason is that `\[ ... \]`, which are macros, do some extra things (sometimes) that `$$ ... $$`, which are baked in to TeX, cannot be made to do.

Answer (score 17):

I suppose it could be useful if you share your files with someone else who doesn't have a syntax-highlighting text editor. Other than that, it probably doesn't matter much. Certainly if nobody else ever sees your LaTeX source files, I'd say write them however you want.

This is neither here nor there, but personally I find neither of those as clear as `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`.

Comment: You meant equation*, didn't you? =p

Comment: Sure, whatever variant it takes to get the effect I want.

Comment: I understand why (so they can post a bunch of LaTeX code without it rendering), but it seems ironic they don't implement MathJax. Also MathJax doesn't recognize \[ \]. And neither does any other Markdown style edit box, eg. Moodle or Canvas learning management systems.

Comment: Also, your answer prompted me to try using \begin{align} \end{align} in Mathjax. It works, but you have to use \newline instead of \\ for the next equation.