# Commas in \cases - typographic standards?

Tags: punctuation, typography

I'm wondering what are the typographic standards for the placement of commas/dots in the following (and similar) case:\
[image]

The first option looks nicer, the second seems to be more logically consistent.

Comment: In the TeXbook Knuth uses something like `\begin{equation}
d=\begin{cases}
  (l+b)^2+p^2,&\text{if $0\le p<10000$};\\
  (l+b)^2-p^2,&\text{if $-10000<p<0$};\\
  (l+b)^2,&\text{if $p\le-10000$}.\end{cases}
\end{equation}`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499/35864

Comment: You may also be interested in what the AMS style guide has to say on the issue (http://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/AMSstyleguide.pdf, §13.11)

Comment: I don't find the second option logically consistent, besides being typographically abominable.

Comment: My goto rule for this is to use the same punctuation that you'd use if this wasn't in display mode, aka the first one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a reference, page 109 of the AMS style guide (http://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/AMSstyleguide.pdf) suggests that the first is preferred (at least by the AMS).