# Semicolons/ commas in align - typographic standards?

Tags: typography, punctuation

This might be more of a typography question.
Say have two equations, and I put them in an aligned environment.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The following equations are true:
\begin{align*}
a^2 + b^2 & = c^2 \\
x^2 + y^2 & = z^2.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Do I need to add a semicolon or a comma after c^2? I know that in the case of a [cases environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521362/commas-in-cases-typographic-standards) it is recommended to do so.

Comment: Did you also read the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521364/224762). According to this [style guide](http://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/AMSstyleguide.pdf) (page 109) a semicolon is recommended. But I am no mathematician so I do not know if there is a concrete rule.

Comment: @Roland I did. If I understand correctly, a semicolon or a comma is recommended in the case of a cases environment. I want to know if the same standard holds for an align environment of a few equations.

Comment: In french typography rules, definitively. Not sure how much international this is then, but I would recommend one.

Comment: As rule of thumb, I typeset such stuff as if it would be linear, and then add some 2D arrangements to enhance readability. So yes, I'd use the same punctuation as if it were a linear sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: add punctuation after your `c^2`.

Long answer:

In general maths is punctuated just as normal text is. The following is a short extract from a document I've been preparing for many years, eventually to be submitted to TUG.

[image]

It is called *Mathematics with Style* and deals in general terms the accepted typeset appearance of mathematics, but not as a "How to do it with (La)TeX".

Comment: Looking forward to read that document.